# Silly question: are polynomials "X" and "X^2" reducible?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Since `f(0)=0` holds for both, are they both reducible polynomials?

I'm asking because I'm working on this question where they're asking you to factor the following in irreducible factors.

```
X^5 - X^4 - X^3 + X^2 + X ∈ F3[X]
```

The solution is X(X^2 + X + 2)^2, so that includes factor X, which I believe is reducible... Am I missing something here?

Comment: As any other polynomial of degree one (over some field) , $\;x\;$ is irreducible, whereas $\;x^2=x\cdot x\;$ is reducible

Comment: Thank you. Guess I got blinded by all the rules I studied and kinda forgot about the simple ones. If you put that in an answer I'll approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As any other polynomial of degree one (over some field) , $x$ is irreducible, whereas $x^2=x\cdot x$ is reducible

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is a linear polynomial so it is irreducible. $x^2$, on the other hand, is not irreducible because it can be factored as the difference of squares:
$x^2 \iff x^2 - 0 \iff x^2 - 0^2 \iff (x-0)(x+0)$